# Difference between acetocarmine and feulgen stain

Tags: experimental-chemistry

We did an experiment on observing mitosis in onion root tip cells, and I have observed that there are two ways of staining it, using acetocarmine and feulgen stain. What are the advantages of using each of them and the disadvantages, if there is one? What would be the difference, after all? Thank you in advance for your kind response.